# Static initializers

Tags: c++, initialization

I'm fiddling around with a possible way to run some chunks of "this stuff needs to be initialized at program start" code while keeping them local to their respective modules, and came up with this:

```
static struct init {
    init() {
        // do stuff
    }
} _;
```

When I put that in module `a.cc` it worked fine. When I put it also in module `b.cc` not so good - A's version was called twice and B's version not at all. I was figuring okay, compiler bug, it's getting confused about the two functions with the same name, but what surprised me was that on further testing, it behaves exactly the same way in Microsoft C++ and GCC. Do both compilers happen to have the same bug, or is there something I'm missing about the language semantics?

Also, any recommendations for workarounds or other ways to achieve the same result (apart from exporting the relevant functions and explicitly calling them from `main` which is obviously the fallback)?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7437137/430766

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *variables* are static and therefore visible only in their respective translation units, but the *types* aren't. How about putting your structs in anonymous namespaces?

Comment: I thought all the unnamed namespace was buying was preventing anyone from externing it. Why does some random cpp have visibility of a type from another cpp?

Comment: That's how *all* cpp files work, @Dave. Usually, structs are defined in a header, and that's how they're guaranteed to be identical in all translation units, but there's nothing stopping you from just duplicating the same definition in each file separately. The compiler doesn't know the difference.

Comment: @RobKennedy Oh, good point - I guess I never thought about that. But in that case why wasn't the OPs situation causes some kind of error for breaking ODR?

Comment: Because for such an error to get caught, the linker would need access to a lot of information linkers don't generally have access to.

Comment: Well, I guess to break ODR you would need multiple definitions in different translation units. In this case there were just _different_ definitions for the same type in _different_ translation units.

Comment: @Dave It _was_ breaking ODR, and that's what was causing the problem. ODR violations cause undefined behavior, not necessarily any kind of diagnostic.